# Is it really better to have an unnecessary function call instead of using else?

Tags: if-statement, coding-style

So I had a discussion with a colleague today. He strongly suggested me to change a code from

```
if(condition){
   function->setValue(true)
}
else{
   function->setValue(false)
}
```

to

```
function->setValue(false)
if(condition){
    function->setValue(true)
}
```

in order to avoid the 'else'. I disagreed, because - while it might improve readability to some degree - in the case of the if-condition being true, we have 1 absolutely unnecessary function call.

What do you guys think?

Comment: What about function->setValue(condition)? If the parameter is not a boolean I recommend the first variant as you never know if setValue has some unwanted side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Meh.

To do this to just to avoid the `else` is silly (at least there should be a deeper rationale). There's no extra branching cost to it typically, especially after the optimizer goes through it.

Code compactness can sometimes be a desirable aesthetic, especially if a lot of time is spent skimming and searching through code than reading it line-by-line. There can be legit reasons to favor terser code sometimes, but it's always cons and pros. But even code compactness should not be about cramming logic into fewer lines of code so much as just straightforward logic.

Correctness here might be easier to achieve with one or the other. The point was made in a comment that you might not know the side effects associated with calling `setValue(false)`, though I would suggest that's kind of moot. Functions should have minimal side effects, they should all be documented at the interface/usage level if they aren't totally obvious, and if we don't know exactly what they are, we should be spending more time looking up their documentation prior to calling them (and their side effects should not be changing once firm dependencies are established to them).

Given that, it may sometimes be easier to achieve correctness and maintain it with a solution that starts out initializing states to some default value, and using a form of code that opts in to overwrite it in specific branches of code. From that standpoint, what your colleague suggested may be valid as a way to avoid tripping over that code in the future. Then again, for a simple if/else pair of branches, it's hardly a big deal.

Don't worry about the cost of the extra most-likely-constant-time function call either way in this kind of knee-deep micro-level implementation case, especially with no super tight performance-critical loop around this code (and even then, still prefer to worry about that at least a little bit in hindsight after profiling).

I think there are far better things to think about than this kind of coding style, like testing procedure. Reliable code tends to need less revisiting, and has the freedom to be written in a wider variety of ways without causing disputes. Testing is what establishes reliability. The biggest disputes about coding style tend to follow teams where there's more toe-stepping and more debugging of the same bodies of code over and over and over from disparate people due to lack of reliability, modularity, excessive coupling, etc. It's a symptom of a problem but not necessarily the root cause.